# Currency symbol to letters in new column

Tags: r, regex, currency

how to separate the currency symbols from the number and make a new column with the symbol replaced by EUR, USD, YEN etc. in a dataframe like this in R:

```
> a
  prices
1 $100.00
2 200.00€
3 75.40¥
4 £51.98
5 154.00 EUR
6 59.00 USD
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
> a
  prices    currency
1 100.00    USD
2 200.00    EUR
3 75.40     JPY
4 51.98     GBP
5 154.00    EUR
6 59.00     USD
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using regex, extract numbers and extract non-numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` functions. There are no built-in converter so I'm afraid you'll have to do the currency symbol/name conversion manually (you can do it with `case_when`).

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  mutate(value = parse_number(prices),
         text = gsub("[0-9.]+", "", prices), 
         text = case_when(text == "$" ~ "USD", 
                          text == "€" ~ "EUR",
                          text == "¥" ~ "YEN", 
                          text == "£" ~ "GBP",
                          T ~ text))
```

output

```r
      prices  value text
1    $100.00 100.00  USD
2    200.00€ 200.00  EUR
3     75.40¥  75.40  YEN
4     £51.98  51.98  GBP
5 154.00 EUR 154.00  EUR
6  59.00 USD  59.00  USD
```

---

data

```r
dat <- read.table(header = T, text = "  prices
1 $100.00
2 200.00€
3 75.40¥
4 £51.98
5 '154.00 EUR'
6 '59.00 USD'")
```

Comment: What to do if there are also currencies which are written in lower-case?
I can't convert them with the same procedure.

Comment: I'm not sure why? It should work the same.

Comment: Now, I get it, use `toupper` as in @Christian's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Maël's answer, but with a `stringr` solution for the regex, but I also threw in a case for dealing with lower case.

```
dat %>% mutate(numbers = str_extract(prices, "[0-9.]+"),
               currency = str_replace(prices, numbers, ""),
               currency = case_when(currency == "$" ~ "USD", 
                                    currency == "€" ~ "EUR",
                                    currency == "¥" ~ "YEN", 
                                    currency == "£" ~ "GBP",
                                    TRUE ~ toupper(currency)))
```